# when i use celery==4.1.0 and redis==4.3.6 error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, redis, celery

Good afternoon. On the project I use celery==4.1.0 and redis==4.3.6 And when I start the celery container I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
     self.blueprint.start(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
     step.start(parent)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 370, in start
     return self.obj.start()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 320, in start
     blueprint.start(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
     step.start(parent)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 596, in start
     c.loop(*c.loop_args())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 88, in asynloop
     next(loop)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 354, in create_loop
     cb(*cbargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1040, in on_readable
     self.cycle.on_readable(fileno)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 337, in on_readable
     chan.handlers[type]()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 724, in _brpop_read
     self.connection._deliver(loads(bytes_to_str(item)), dest)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 981, in _deliver
     callback(message)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 632, in _callback
     self.qos.append(message, message.delivery_tag)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 149, in append
     pipe.zadd(self.unacked_index_key, time(), delivery_tag) \
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 4005, in zadd
     for pair in mapping.items():
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'
```

This happens when using any version of redis>=3.0.0. When I set redis==2.10.6 celery works fine. But I need redis version >= 3.0.0. Please help me fix everything.

I tried different versions of redis, but I have python == 3.6 on my project and it is very problematic to upgrade the python version. Please help me to solve the problem without changing the version of python.

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of redis from (redis-py 3.0), the method signature has changed. Along with ZADD, MSET and MSETNX signatures were also changed.

The old signature was:

```
data = "hello world"
score = 1 
redis.zadd("redis_key_name", data, score) # not used in redis-py > 3.0
```

The new signature is:

```
data = "hello world"
score = 1 

redis.zadd("redis_key_name", {data: score})
```